# Is there any way I can run the DBT snapshot with running the Post Hook command?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have DBT snapshot job wherein I have a post-hook to update the delete entries with the current timestamp.

Now, I want to run the same job for full load and delta load.

When I run the full load, I do not want the post-hook to run. Post-hook should run only for the delta runs.

Is there any way we can ignore the post-hook query while running the full load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a macro that executes whatever your post hook does and put the condition inside the macro using a jinja `if` statement. Call the macro from your post hook and pass whatever drives the job type

Comment: The condition will be passed from airflow. Also, i am looking forward to a generic solution something which can possibly be setup at a DBT account or environment level, if that's a possibility.

Comment: Yep, that's what my answer gives you - put all your logic in the macro, and call the macro from your post hook every single time. Your macro can check for some environment variable or argument that tells it the job type, and your macro can just noop `if job_type == 'FULL_LOAD'`